# Change order of cells in order to send email, then change them back

Tags: email, excel, vba

Is it possible to have a macro that changes the order of the cells within an excel doc, and then immediately changes them back?

In Column C I have a list of dates. I would ideally like to have the macro order all of the rows by date, send the email I need in this order, and then have it go back to the (more or less) random order it is in now.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible

Comment: Almost anything is possible in VBA.

Comment: Record a macro using the steps you described above.  use ctrl-z to UNDO the sort after the email is sent.  stop recording, review what was recorded and tweek to fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you were wondering this is how you sort the dates

```
Sub SortByDate()
 Dim rSortRange As Range
 Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rSortRange = ws.Range("N11", "N111")
rSortRange.Sort Key1:=ws.Range("N11"), Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

And you can run this code to send a email if you are using outlook

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendEmail).Show
```